# confusion in reference type in solidity

Tags: solidity, compiler, data-types

Suppose a struct is made in solidity and pushed the same struct to an array and a mapping (assume a random key), will the change in struct accessed through mapping will affect the change in the same element pushed inside array?

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StudentVerify {
   struct abc{
    string name;
    uint roll;
    uint8 sem;
   }

    abc[] public Array;
    mapping(uint => abc) public mapper;

    function setter(string memory _name, uint _roll,uint8 _sem) public {
        abc memory f = abc(_name,_roll,_sem);
        mapper[_roll] = f;
        Array.push(f);
    }
    
 function MapSetter( uint _roll,uint8 _sem) public {
        mapper[_roll].sem = _sem;
    }
```

suppose in the example I changed the semester of a student accessed through his/her roll number (mapping). will the change be also seen when Array[0](say the student is in that index when pushed) is accessed?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.

We use different objects: `mapper` as HashMap and `Array` as array. They are not related in this example

Comment: But according to different programming language since struct  is a reference type, why fetching and modifying the value of fields that in within a struct referenced by multiple type in different wouldn't affect the value? Please help me since I am very beginner to this :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even in another language the result will be the same - you have created two different objects and they court independent of each other

Comment: It's just that these objects have a struct abc{...}  as part of them